# Wireshark analysis and RTT graph

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark, analysis

I'm working on a Wireshark capture analysis. In that session we have a request to an FTP server for a file provided by it. Trying to get the RTT time, i follow the TCP stream starting with the request and then i get the graph FOR RTT from **Statistics>TCP Stream Graphs>Round Trip Time**. Below, you can see the graph i get and a line i draw on the 10ms barrier(default ping time). As you can see, most of the packets have RTT of around 1ms, but some are over 10ms.

Can someone tell me if i can measure those with RTT over 10ms? Also, would someone say that the number of those packets is ignorable(maybe because they are a lot less than those under 10ms)?

[image: RTT graph of the stream i'm interested in]

Comment: I think the way i described my problem might not be the best, but it is the first time using network analysis software. If you need more to provide me with some advice/help, please ask.

Comment: I'm not clear on your query. What do you mean by "measuring" packets with RTT over 10 ms? Do you need to count them or get average RTT or collect RTT values into spreadsheet or what? Regarding ignoring packets, it's always up to your requirements. There is no standard or common rule to determine if delay is acceptable.